# BOM Problem for matching 2 keys' value with TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator()

Tags: java, csv, matching, treemap

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on this page (https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-upload-csv-file/)  in order to insert information from a csv file into a mysql DB but I got stuck by something in the class CSVHelper.

While doing my search, I've found the problem was located in `TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator()` where the key value doesn't match with any of the values of the `headerMap`.
When I checked the variables in the Debug view, I saw the first values were different whereas the text was the same ("Id").

- The key argument ("Id") has for value [73, 100]
- The headersMap ("Id") has for value [-1, -2, 73, 0, 100, 0]

[image: Key argument value]

[image: HeadersMap value]

I have checked the header in the file and there's no space. Otherwise, all the other headers work fine.

**After changing the order of the headers, it spotlights that the problem is for the 1st header name. It adds [-1,-2] at the beginning and 0 between the other values.**

So, what do you think it can possibly be ? What can I do to solve this ?

[Project on Github, branch dev-mysql-csv](https://github.com/chyuga9/tuto-files-app.git)

Answer (score 0):

This change at the beginning of the input was the consequence of the [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The csv file wasn't saved at the good format (I changed from "csv delimited with comma" to "csv delimited with semicolon") then it worked.
But this is ok only when the separator was "," and not ";" that is very odd...

In order to handle the BOM, there is [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html). I succeeded to run "csv delimited with comma".
I tried to use withRecordSeparator(";") and withDelimiter(";") in order to make it work with ";" but it failed.